# How can I send JSON data to and from ROS?

Tags: ros, rosbridge-server, roslibjs

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am currently working on a task that involves constant intercommunication between a web browser (using roslibjs) and the ROS system through the rosbridge server. Is there a way to send JSON-formatted data from the browser to a ROS node? I realize there is no JSON among the ROS system's standard data types.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/275012/how-can-i-send-json-data-to-and-from-ros?/) by [qureeb](https://answers.ros.org/users/32505/qureeb/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2017-11-05

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-11-05**:
I'm confused: if you are already using `roslibjs` and `rosbridge_suite`, you *are* sending (and receiving) JSON data to (and from) ROS.

Can you clarify what it is you actually want to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

(follow up to my comment)

If you want to send JSON encoded data as part of a message to a ROS node, then I don't believe there are any special provisions for that.

Most straightforward would probably be to define a new message that stores the JSON string in a field. Any receiving node will have to know it's JSON though.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-11-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thanks, I found a way out. I was expecting JSON to be one of ROS's standard message types. Not the case. I simply wrote a JSON-format data, stringified it, and sent it as std_msgs type.

---

Originally posted by [qureeb](https://answers.ros.org/users/32505/qureeb/) with karma: 41 on 2017-11-21

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2017-11-21**:
This will certainly work. However it's not recommended since you're completely avoiding the message datatype checks and all the introspection tools are unable to help you. As @gvdhoorn suggests the recommended way to do this would be to define a custom message to hold your data.

**Comment by [AhteshamAziz](https://answers.ros.org/users/44710/ahteshamaziz/) on 2019-10-07**:
but what if you want that stringified  data into json form in c++ side.

**Comment by [qureeb](https://answers.ros.org/users/32505/qureeb/) on 2019-11-26**:
@AhteshamAziz Then you need the C++ equivalent of Javascript's JSON.parse() utility, which can construct JSON object from a JSON-formatted String.